# How do I apply only horizontal cell spacing to a HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

I recently found out that I need to use the cellspacing attribute in my table, but I was wondering if I could get it to work only horizontally. I don't want it to vertically spread out, that messes up the layout of my entire page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set cellspacing in tables only horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970826/how-to-set-cellspacing-in-tables-only-horizontally)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A better way than setting `cellspacing="10"` is to use CSS. You can use the following CSS to target the table's cell spacing.

```
table {
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
```

The first value specifies the horizontal spacing, and the second value specifies the vertical spacing.

Comment: The `border-spacing` property is not recognized by IE 8 and earlier.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Chrome.  A transparent border as described here does:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656207/css-horizontal-table-cell-spacing-how

Comment: you also need to add `border-collapse: separate;` for this to work

Comment: It will also not work for an email received by an Outlook client

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I know it's ugly and abhorrent to the separation of content and styling, but adding spacer (invisible) columns seems the only thing that consistently works across all platforms.

Here I put some empty table data in the first row and gave them a width (in pixels). I made corresponding empty table data in the successive rows.  It feels real *old school*, but it's simple and works.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some content for column 1</td>
        <td width="18" />
        <td>other content for 2nd visible column (actually column 3)</td>
        <td width="18" />
        <td>content for 3rd visible column (actually column 5)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src="image_for_column 1.png" /></td>
        <td />
        <td><img src="image_for_column 2.png" /></td>
        <td />
        <td><img src="image_for_column 3.png" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that though this works visually, it messes with the content and semantics. A preferred method would facilitate CSS and not interfere with the way other (non-visual) systems interpret the data.

Comment: @ACJ Did you read the first part of the first sentence?  I whole-heartedly acknowledge this limitation.  But this is included for completeness.  And sometimes the extra time taken for setting up a new CSS file isn't worth it--old school.

Comment: Yes, I did. I felt like providing some emphasis and clarification as this issue is important to me.

Comment: I think this is the only answer for things like HTML tables for emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set cell *contents* apart, use spacing inside cells (and set `cellspacing=0` in HTML). This is universally supported by CSS-enabled browsers.

If you really need to separate the cells themselves, so that there is spacing between their borders or their colored background, then `border-spacing` would solve the problem, but only in supporting browsers.

Depending on the context, you might even consider simulating cell spacing by putting cell contents in a `div`, set to cover the cell area except desired padding, which will then look like cell spacing. You would then set any desired border or background on those `div` elements.