# How to set cellspacing in tables only horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table, cellspacing

I would like to style the table written below.

```
<table border="1"   cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that cellspacing sets the space between cells both horizontaly and verticaly, I would like it to be done only horizontaly. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Can you try with CSS by setting padding-left and padding-right to your TDs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing) CSS property on the table. Browser support is fairly good (excluding mainly IE up to and including IE 7). Example:

```
table { border-spacing: 10px 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try CSS

```
table td{

 padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; /* top right bottom left */

 }
```

Comment: Padding is inside cells. It’s different from spacing between cells, which is what this is about.